# put already known coefficient to the new dataset to predict new y

Tags: sas

all.

I have already got output from logistic regression, those coefficients. I would like to plug those coefficients into new data set and use the variables in the new data set but the old coefficients to predict new "y". What should I do?I have already tried proc score, but not sure if it is the proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use `PROC Logistic Inmodel` statement, See the example from SAS documentation [here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_logistic_sect066.htm):-

```
proc logistic inmodel = your_coefficient_file_from_logistic_run;
    score data= new_dataset_to_score out=new_scored_dataset;
run;
```

Let me know if you have any questions